# SQL IN by multiple columns in Slick

Tags: sql, scala, slick

I want to express something like

```
WHERE (col1, col2)
IN ((val1a, val2a), (val1b, val2b), ...)
```

In pseudo-Slick:

```
val values = Set(("val1a", "val2a"), ("val1b", "val2b"))
// and in filter
(col1, col2) inSetBind values
```

Is there a way to do that in Slick?

Comment: What about `.filter((_.col1, _.col2) in values)`

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh did you try it?